# Kivy switching widgets using a toolbar

Tags: user-interface, kivy, kivy-language

I'm trying to make a monitoring app where you can switch which stat would be the main widget. I was thinking of having a screen manager and then having separate screens for each stat, but it seemed like there would be a better way.

Below is my kv file where I have separate screens for each layout and the tool bar is outside of the screens:

```
<Mytest>
    GridLayout
        cols: 1
        size: root.size
        StackLayout:
            
            orientation: 'lr-tb'
            size_hint_y: .05
            Button:
                text: "pog"
                size_hint_x: .1
                background_color: (0, 0, 0, 0)
                on_press: root.ids.manager.current = 'first'
                
            Button:
                text: "p"
                size_hint_x: .1
                background_color: (0, 0, 0, 0)
                on_press: root.ids.manager.current = 'second'
            Button:
                text: " o"
                size_hint_x: .1
                background_color: (0, 0, 0, 0)
                on_press: root.ids.manager.current = 'third'
            Button:
                text: "G"
                size_hint_x: .1
                background_color: (0, 0, 0, 0)
                on_press: root.ids.manager.current = 'fourth'

        ScreenManager:
            id:manager
            Screen:
                name: 'first'
                GridLayout:
                    cols: 2
                    rows: 1
                    GridLayout:
                        cols: 1
                        spacing: (3, 5)
                        Label:
                            text:"Idk"
                            canvas.before:
                                Color: 
                                    rgba: (.2, 1, 1, 1)
                                Rectangle:
                                    pos: self.pos
                                    size: self.size
                        Label:
                            text:"Idk"
                            canvas.before:
                                Color: 
                                    rgba: (1, 1, .2, 1)
                                Rectangle:
                                    pos: self.pos
                                    size: self.size
                        Label:
                            text:"Idk"
                            canvas.before:
                                Color: 
                                    rgba: (0, 1, 0, 1)
                                Rectangle:
                                    pos: self.pos
                                    size: self.size
                    Splitter:
                        sizeable_from: "left"
                        strip_size: "7pt"
                        Label:
                            text:"POGER"
                            canvas.before:
                                Color: 
                                    rgba: (1, 0, 0, 1)
                                Rectangle:
                                    pos: self.pos
                                    size: self.size
            Screen:
                name: 'second'
                GridLayout:
                    cols: 2
                    rows: 1
                    GridLayout:
                        cols: 1
                        spacing: (3, 5)
                        Label:
                            text:"POGER"
                            canvas.before:
                                Color: 
                                    rgba: (1, 0, 0, 1)
                                Rectangle:
                                    pos: self.pos
                                    size: self.size
                        Label:
                            text:"Idk"
                            canvas.before:
                                Color: 
                                    rgba: (1, 1, .2, 1)
                                Rectangle:
                                    pos: self.pos
                                    size: self.size
                        Label:
                            text:"Idk"
                            canvas.before:
                                Color: 
                                    rgba: (0, 1, 0, 1)
                                Rectangle:
                                    pos: self.pos
                                    size: self.size
                    Splitter:
                        sizeable_from: "left"
                        strip_size: "7pt"
                        Label:
                            text:"Idk"
                            canvas.before:
                                Color: 
                                    rgba: (.2, 1, 1, 1)
                                Rectangle:
                                    pos: self.pos
                                    size: self.size
            Screen:
                name: 'third'
                GridLayout:
                    cols: 2
                    rows: 1
                    GridLayout:
                        cols: 1
                        spacing: (3, 5)
                        Label:
                            text:"Idk"
                            canvas.before:
                                Color: 
                                    rgba: (.2, 1, 1, 1)
                                Rectangle:
                                    pos: self.pos
                                    size: self.size
                        Label:
                            text:"POGER"
                            canvas.before:
                                Color: 
                                    rgba: (1, 0, 0, 1)
                                Rectangle:
                                    pos: self.pos
                                    size: self.size
                        Label:
                            text:"Idk"
                            canvas.before:
                                Color: 
                                    rgba: (0, 1, 0, 1)
                                Rectangle:
                                    pos: self.pos
                                    size: self.size
                    Splitter:
                        sizeable_from: "left"
                        strip_size: "7pt"
                        Label:
                            text:"Idk"
                            canvas.before:
                                Color: 
                                    rgba: (1, 1, .2, 1)
                                Rectangle:
                                    pos: self.pos
                                    size: self.size
            Screen:
                name: 'fourth'
                GridLayout:
                    cols: 2
                    rows: 1
                    GridLayout:
                        cols: 1
                        spacing: (3, 5)
                        Label:
                            text:"Idk"
                            canvas.before:
                                Color: 
                                    rgba: (.2, 1, 1, 1)
                                Rectangle:
                                    pos: self.pos
                                    size: self.size
                        Label:
                            text:"Idk"
                            canvas.before:
                                Color: 
                                    rgba: (1, 1, .2, 1)
                                Rectangle:
                                    pos: self.pos
                                    size: self.size
                        Label:
                            text:"POGER"
                            canvas.before:
                                Color: 
                                    rgba: (1, 0, 0, 1)
                                Rectangle:
                                    pos: self.pos
                                    size: self.size
                    Splitter:
                        sizeable_from: "left"
                        strip_size: "7pt"
                        Label:
                            text:"Idk"
                            canvas.before:
                                Color: 
                                    rgba: (0, 1, 0, 1)
                                Rectangle:
                                    pos: self.pos
                                    size: self.size




            # GridLayout:
            #     cols: 2
            #     rows: 1
            #     GridLayout:
            #         cols: 1
            #         spacing: (3, 5)
            #         Label:
            #             text:"Idk"
            #             canvas.before:
            #                 Color: 
            #                     rgba: (1, 0, 0, 1)
            #                 Rectangle:
            #                     pos: self.pos
            #                     size: self.size
            #         Label:
            #             text:"Idk"
            #             canvas.before:
            #                 Color: 
            #                     rgba: (1, 1, .2, 1)
            #                 Rectangle:
            #                     pos: self.pos
            #                     size: self.size
            #         Label:
            #             text:"POGER"
            #             canvas.before:
            #                 Color: 
            #                     rgba: (.2, 1, 1, 1)
            #                 Rectangle:
            #                     pos: self.pos
            #                     size: self.size
            #     Splitter:
            #         sizeable_from: "left"
            #         strip_size: "7pt"
            #         Label:
            #             text:"IDK"
            #             canvas.before:
            #                 Color: 
            #                     rgba: (0, 1, 0, 1)
            #                 Rectangle:
            #                     pos: self.pos
            #                     size: self.size
```

The python file is just the imports and then building the app:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle, Color
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.pagelayout import PageLayout
from kivy.uix.splitter import Splitter
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
```

Answer (score 0):

Good day. I recommend a class in python that could hold the values for a given stat. When you change the stat, call a function that loads each attribute of the stat into the main widget. Each stat will be its own object.

Comment: If I have it right, load the stats and surrounding data into a class and then have a switch statement to swap where the data is called to, like the main widget or side ones.

Comment: What you are considering is close to a Factory Design Pattern. I would work.